# компилирование с помощью pyinstaller. Не пакует библиотеку Ta-lib

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Откомпилировал. при запуске в PowerShell выдает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "balance.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "talib\__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'talib.stream'[18092] Failed to execute script 'balance' due to unhandled exception!
```

Насколько моя пустая голова поняла - при компиляции не прошел модуль библиотеки Talib. Может кто сталкивался с проблемой? почему это могло произойти? Запускал по разному. и CMD и PowerShell.... и перекомпилировал... толку - 0. Хелп